# Yii - controller - function to change a flag/boolean on db

Tags: php, object, frameworks, model, yii

I'm working on a project with Yii. I am working on the backend, at the moment.
I'm implementing a function in a controller that should load a model, change a value in the database (a tinyint that changes from 0 to 1) for that particular model and redirect to another url.
I want to use this function in the same way as it's used the "delete" function generated by the CRUD generator.
So inspiring myself on the "delete" function, I am trying this one for the "accept" function:

```
    public function actionAccept($id) {
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        $model->testimonial_accepted = '1';
        $model->save();

        // if AJAX request we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }
```

I am calling the "accept" function in a view, like this:

```
     array('label'=>'Accept Client', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('accept','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to accept this item?')),
```

When run, there's no error. It loads the right model but it doesn't change the value in the database (testimonial_accepted). Do you have any idea why? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Supialios.

Comment: check wheather the $model->save() function is returing true , ie there is any validation error. Or as a workaround use $model->save(false)

Comment: Note that Yii provides functionality to check if the request is an AJAX request: `Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest`. Also, if you only want an action to be available using the POST method, you can specify `'postOnly + accept'` in the array returned by your controller's `filters()` method. This way you can simplify your code even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if this works:

```
$model->save( false );
```

If it works, this mean that model's data is not saved because validation fail (e.g. check model's rules and eventually define new scenario).

And in this case I think it's more appropriate to use *update* instead of *save* method:

```
$model->setAttribute( 'testimonial_accepted', 1 );
$model->update( array( 'testimonial_accepted' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your link, the path should be in a form of `<controller>/<action>` so let's say your controller name is `foo` then you should say:

```
array('submit'=>array('foo/accept','id'=>$model->id)
```

and i agree with @Boris, you should use update and moreover data manipulation code is better to be in model to follow MVC best practices, so it will look like this:

**controller:**

```
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        $model->acceptTestimonial(); // a model function
        $this->redirect(array('action_you_choose'));
```

**Model:**

```
public function acceptTestimonial()
{
    $this->testimonial_accepted = '1';
    $this->update(array('testimonial_accepted'));
}
```